# How to translate Firefox add-on?

Tags: localization, firefox-addon

Trying to [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension#Localization) [SynoExt addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/synoext/).

I've added to:

**chrome.manifest**:

```
locale synoext en-US chrome/locale/en-US/
locale synoext ru-RU chrome/locale/ru-RU/
```

**preferences.xul**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://synoext/locale/translation.dtd">

<prefwindow id="SynoPrefWindow" title="&SynoPrefWindow.title;"
```

and created folders **chrome\locale\en-US** and **chrome\locale\ru-RU** with files **translation.dtd**:

```
<!ENTITY SynoPrefWindow.title "SynoExt Preferences">
```

And I am getting error:

```
<prefwindow id="SynoPrefWindow" title="&SynoPrefWindow.title;"
^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your complete `preferences.xul`? It's not well-formed XML.

Comment: @lwburk, surely, no. These are just first 4 lines of that file (for complete code please see SynoExt url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of error was incorrect encoding (ANSI instead of UTF-8) used in my RU translation file.

Answer (score 1):

If your root tag is prefwindow you need to define prefwindow as DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE prefwindow [
  <!ENTITY % translationsDTD SYSTEM "chrome://synoext/locale/translation.dtd">
  %translationsDTD;
]>

<prefwindow id="SynoPrefWindow" title="&SynoPrefWindow.title;"
            xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    ...
</prefwindow>
```

For reference, you could check out, for instance, the code for [Identity Chooser](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/files/browse/124437/), one of my extensions.